# packed structs in tcc

Tags: c, struct, tcc, packed

I am trying to do packed struct in tcc C compiller. 
Code is as follows and __attribute __ tag should be supported:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct _test_t{
    char        c;
    uint16_t    i;
    char        d;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) test_t;

int main(){
    test_t x;
    x.c = 0xCC;
    x.i = 0xAABB;
    x.d = 0xDD;

    const char *s = (const char *) & x;

    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
        printf("%3u %x\n", i, 0xFF & s[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

It works in gcc, but not work on tcc. 
I also tried __attribute __((packed)) and few other tests - none works.

Comment: tcc and gcc are different compilers, using different syntax for extensions (like `__attribute__`). AFAIK tcc is no longer maintained, so why to use it anyway?

Comment: I was curios if my code is portable and tried with tcc. It did compiled without a warning. However I need packed structs and according to tcc documentation it supports it.

Comment: just another 5 cents -  above test works on clang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found the `__attribute__` [extension](http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC8) applies only to struct's members, so each of them should have it applied individually. Here is your code with minor adaptations, that compiles with `tcc` 0.9.26 and then runs with correct output:

```
typedef struct {
    char             c __attribute__((packed));
    unsigned short   i __attribute__((packed));
    char             d __attribute__((packed));
} test_t;

int main(void)
{
    test_t x;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(test_t));

    x.c = 0xCC;
    x.i = 0xAABB;
    x.d = 0xDD;

    const char *s = (const char *) &x;

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
        printf("%3u %x\n", i, 0xFF & s[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
4
  0 cc
  1 bb
  2 aa
  3 dd
```

There is one catch here. As you may already spotted there are no headers. The correctly written code should have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // then replace unsigned short with uint16_t
```

However, with headers the `__attribute__` is no longer working. I am not sure if that always happen, but on my system (CentOS 6) it does exactly in that way.

As I found the explanation lies in internal `sys/cdefs.h` header, that contains:

```
/* GCC has various useful declarations that can be made with the
   `__attribute__' syntax.  All of the ways we use this do fine if
   they are omitted for compilers that don't understand it. */
#if !defined __GNUC__ || __GNUC__ < 2
# define __attribute__(xyz) /* Ignore */
#endif
```

so the `__attribute__` function-like macro is "washed-up" for `tcc`, as it does not define `__GNUC__` macro. It seems to be some incoherence between `tcc` developers and standard library (here `glibc`) writers.

Comment: Tried that, does not work with mine tcc. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that at least with tcc 0.9.26 **attribute**((packed)) on
struct members is not working. Using Windows-style packing pragmas works just fine:

```
    #if defined(__TINYC__)
    #pragma pack(1)
    #endif

    typedef struct {
            uint16_t ..
    } interrupt_gate_descriptor_t;

    #if defined(__TINYC__)
    #pragma pack(1)
    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be error with TCC.

according many sources , including this one, http://wiki.osdev.org/TCC

this should work:

```
struct some_struct {
   unsigned char a __attribute__((packed));
   unsigned char b __attribute__((packed));
} __attribute__((packed));
```

... but it does not work.